# Обновление UI в свете изменений лицензии Creative Commons

Tags: обсуждение, лицензирование

В [предыдущем обновлении](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344491/260198) компания хотела прояснить проблемы и ответить на вопросы о переходе на версию 4.0 лицензии CC BY-SA, а также обязались публиковать обновления по части пользовательского интерфейса. [Свершилось](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347758/260198). На данный момент изменения UI действуют в масштабе всей сети, включая отображение соответствующих версий CC для всех публикаций и комментариев на всех сайтах, обновлены футеры, API и других связанные сайты.

**Предыдущее обновление определило изменение лицензии с CC BY-SA 3.0 на 4.0. Что именно произошло в эту дату?**

До этой даты Terms of Service ссылались на CC BY-SA [3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). В этот день ссылка изменилась и стала указывать на лицензию [4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/). Обновление было как часть процесса, который не проводился Командой сообщества, и в то время не было публичного объявления из-за внутренней неразберихи.

**В таком случае, как насчёт перехода с CC BY-SA 2.5 на 3.0, который произошёл [в апреле 2011 года](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95033/260198)? Разве изменения не должны распространиться и на ту смену лицензии?**

Изменение лицензии, которое было опубликовано на MSE и вступило в силу с 8 апреля 2011 г. (переход с версии 2.5 до версии 3.0), также не могло задним числом изменить лицензию на контент. В новом обновлённом пользовательском интерфейсе будет отражаться соответствующая версия лицензии для контента, соответствено.

Исходя из этого, мы будем применять следующие правила, относящиеся к классификации лицензий на контент, публикуемый на сайте:

- Контент, добавленный до 08.04.2011 (UTC), распространяется в соответствии с условиями [CC BY-SA 2.5](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/).
- Контент, опубликованный с 08.04.2011 до, но не включая 02.05.2018 (UTC), распространяется в соответствии с условиями [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).
- Контент, добавленный 02.05.2018 или позднее (UTC), распространяется в соответствии с условиями [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/).

**Что по поводу правок? Могут ли правки изменить лицензию на контент, который уже был размещён на сайте?**

- Каждый раз, когда часть контента публикуется, результат публикуется в соответствии с версией CC BY-SA в зависимости от даты.
- Каждый раз, когда часть контента на сайте редактируется, создаётся новая версия. Эта новая версия считается переизданной и, следовательно, регулируется версией CC BY-SA, действующей на день внесения изменений.
- Каждая ревизия создаёт новую версию и лицензируется отдельно. Таким образом, текущая версия любой части контента (которая появляется на сайте) является самой последней версией и будет иметь версию лицензии.
- Это применимо независимо от размера, величины или значимости правки. **Примечание**: откаты не создают новых версий, поскольку они не добавляют никакого контента к уже опубликованному.
- Новые правки не изменяют лицензию, которая закреплена за старой ревизией того же контента. Эта старая редакция по-прежнему лицензируется под своей первоначальной версией CC BY-SA.

Изменения пользовательского интерфейса прояснят (через страницу временной шкалы) версию лицензии, которая применяется к каждой ревизии для каждого вопроса, ответа и комментария на всех сайтах.

**Как это выглядит?**

На странице шкалы времени можно посмотреть информацию по всем ревизиям и их лицензии. К примеру, у [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/272283/timeline).

> [image: Временная шкала]

Версию лицензии комментария под сообщением можно посмотреть, просто наведя на него.

> [image: Лицензия комментария]

Comment: Но я всё равно повредничаю и побеспокоюсь насчёт того, имеют ли гиперссылки в ToS юридическую силу

Comment: @andreymal всегда недоволен (¬‿¬ )

Comment: как же всё забюрократизировано!